# SE PODRIA ORDENAR EL CAMPO count en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, select, contador, count, orderby

Hola Buenas el profesor me pide esto:
*Contar el número de autores ordenados por país, ordenados de forma
alfabética. **B) **Ordénalo también por el número de autores de forma
descendente.*****
NO SE COMO LE PUEDO HACER PARA ORDENAR EL CONTEO DE LOS AUTORES DE FORMA DESCENDENTE. HE PROBADO CON ORDER BY COUNT DESC PERO NO ME DEJA.

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta mostrando el código de tu intento

Comment: Órden alfabético de que columna? Es decir por nombre de autor o por país?